# Getting object from NSSet passing test

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsset

This should be pretty easy.  I have an NSSet of People objects.  How do I get the object of a person whose last name is first alphabetically within the set?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect the set to be large you could use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [peopleSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
People *person = nil;
if (sortedArray) {
    person = sortedArray[0];
}
```

Comment: Sorting is expensive if the only need is the first object. At best, a sort usually takes n•Log(n) iterations, and that's for a really good sort operations. To find the first object in a set/array of n objects you only need to do n comparisons.

Comment: If the set is very small and he can perform a sort on a background thread then it doesn't matter. I agree it's not ideal

Answer (score 0):

Write a method firstObjectInSet:usingComparator:

You could even make it a category method on NSSet.

In the method, you would simply loop through the objects in the set (probably using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock). You'd need to define a local (_block) variable firstObject outiside the set. and for each iteration, if the new object comes before the previous object, replace firstObject with the new object. Then after the enumeration is done, return firstObject as the method result. That would always do exactly one pass through the set and return the first object.

If you don't need to be that flexible, drop the NSComparator parameter, and hard-code a method to find the first object.